# Which constructed languages have been used to write scientific articles?

Tags: list-of-languages

One of the most interesting aspects of Interlingua is that during its early days there were a number of scientific articles published in it. This is in contrast with most other constructed languages, which are primarily used to publish things that are of interest only to their own communities.

Have other constructed languages been used for that purpose?

Comment: This seems like a list question to me, and therefore too broad. Do you have any way to make it less broad?

Comment: Maybe this question would be better if it only asked about auxiliary languages like Interlingua or Occidental. Also would articles/papers about linguistics be considered "scientific articles that aren't of interest only to their own communities"?

Comment: I don't see a problem with question that may result in lists of languages. We have a similar tag on [linguistics.se]

Comment: @jknappen We let those questions slide because collectively they form a language typology, similar to [WALS](http://wals.info/). This site may also decide it wants to allow questions to form its own sort of typology, but for now I think we should follow the general rule that list questions don't fit the SE format.

Comment: Even on linguistics I doubt this would be accepted as it's much more a trivia question about languages rather than analysis of languages or building an inventory of languages which fit some narrow criteria.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not convinced. This question is clearly answerable, and the (potential) answers add some value for later vistors of SE.

Comment: @curiousdannii Of course, *this* particular question would be off-topic on linguistics.se, because it is more about the speech community of conlangs and not about linguistic aspects of them. But linguistics.se is a different site ...

Answer (score 6):

The Occidental magazine [*Cosmoglotta*](http://cosmoglotta.blogspot.com.au) occasionally published scientific articles.

In the 32nd publication of Cosmoglotta, a ["supplement"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym9KW.jpg) was added to the magazine, stating that it was "necessary to use the language not only in linguistics articles". The first "scientific article" appears in the [33rd publication of Cosmoglotta](http://cosmoglotta.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/nr-33-march-1926-supplement.html), which published an article about Wegener's theory of continental drift. The publications that follow also contain articles about biology and physics as well as philosophy, economics and politics.

Answer (score 4):

Esperanto is not only used to write scientific articles but there is also a scientific journal published in Esperato, namely [Science Revuo](https://aktuale.scienca-revuo.info/).

Comment: See also [Where can I read interesting articles about science in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/97/860) over at Esperanto.SE.